# Conditions inside a TabView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a TabView in which I want to add another page only if the condition checks out. Unfortunately, I am not able to add another page. I have noticed that all the pages inside a tab view are only created when the tabview is initialized. is there any way to refresh a tabview?

```
struct Demo2: View {
    @State private var showNextTab = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Tab1")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showNextTab = true
                }
            
            if showNextTab {
                Text("Tab2")
            }
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set id to the `TabView`. This will refresh the TabView.

```
TabView {
    Text("Tab1")
        .onTapGesture {
            self.showNextTab = true
        }
    
    if showNextTab {
        Text("Tab2")
    }
}
.id(showNextTab) // << Here
```